# Can't get Android two-way data binding to work (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, data-binding

I am facing a problem where I can't get two-way data binding to work in IntelliJ IDEA. One-way binding works fine.

Here is my setup:

> IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2.1
>
> Android API: 24
>
> Java: 1.8.0_102
>
> Gradle: 2.14.1

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

Here is the layout.xml (one-way binding):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable name="customer"   type="com.example.xyz.model.Customer"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@{Integer.toString(customer.age)}"
              tools:text="33"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{customer.name}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Customer class:

```
public class Customer extends BaseObservable {
private String name;
private int age;

@Bindable
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Bindable
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}}
```

This works just fine for one-way data binding, however when I try two way data binding by changing this line to the following:

```
android:text="@={customer.name}"
```

First, the syntax is not recognized (turns red in IntelliJ) with error: "Missing /"....and the compiler error is:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.EditText.
> file:C:\Source\Android\test\app\src\main\res\layout\test_layout.xml
> loc:24:33 - 24:43
> ****\ data binding error ****

Is two-way data binding not supported in IntelliJ yet, or what am I missing?

Comment: This feels like you are pulling in an old data binding framework. Make sure you are on the latest Android Plugin for Gradle -- in Android Studio, this would be in your top-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA, not Android Studio. The Android SDK version, Gradle version, etc. are in my post above.

Comment: "I am using IntelliJ IDEA, not Android Studio" -- I know. However, I do not use IDEA, and I do not know where in an IDEA project the Android Plugin for Gradle version goes. Hence, I pointed out where it belongs in an Android Studio project, as a point of reference. "The Android SDK version, Gradle version, etc. are in my post above" -- those are not [the Android Plugin for Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html). The Android Plugin for Gradle is what allows you to have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in the Gradle script shown in your question.

Comment: I am not sure myself - I don't have this entry in the Gradle script at all. I can set which Gradle version to be used for the project, but I am not sure what the correspondence between Android Studio Gradle plugin version and the IntelliJ Gradle tool version is.

Comment: "I am not sure what the correspondence between Android Studio Gradle plugin version and the IntelliJ Gradle tool version is" -- they are independent but loosely coupled, insofar as different plugin versions have different ranges of supported Gradle versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, based on the info from these slides:

> http://www.slideshare.net/radekpiekarz/deep-dive-into-android-data-binding

1. In the project's top-level `build.gradle` file, gradle:2.1.0 or above is needed. I had it set to gradle:2.0.0, even though I had the latest version installed. I am guessing this is the Android Gradle plugin version that @CommonsWare is referring to. Here is my corrected top-level `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
2. After fixing the gradle version, IntelliJ IDEA still highlights the syntax as error, but the project compiles fine. However, the two-way data binding itself still did not work. To fix that part, I added `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)` to the `name` property setter in the Customer class:

   ```
   public class Customer extends BaseObservable {
       private String name;
       private int age;

       @Bindable
       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
       }

       @Bindable
       public int getAge() {
           return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
          this.age = age;
       }
   }
   ```

After this, the binding works as expected - I did not need to add any extra adapters or more code.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the attribute `android:text` databindings try to call some `getText()` on the `EditText` expecting a return type of `String`. But since it returns a `CharSequence` you have to define this getter yourself.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static String captureTextValue(TextView view) {
    return view.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I am new to Android - could you please explain where I am supposed to place this adapter, and how to hook it up with my existing code? I also looked here, but I still don't understand how the entire example would look like: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter.html

Comment: @A.Abrams This documentation is of no big value yet. There were some changes not reflected and you'll find some obvious error there as well. In the end you could put this adapter anywhere. I used a static utility class for this. The hooking is done automatically.