# Android Data binding 'Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, exception, android-databinding

I am facing Error while making the project due to Data binding. 
I fail to understand their logs and the Exception stack trace.

The Entire grade console error says

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlavorSuperwiseDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
  >   cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException
  >   at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelMethod.isBoxingConversion(ModelMethod.java:155)
  >   at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.isBetterParameter(SetterStore.java:946)
  >   at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getBestSetter(SetterStore.java:838)

..
...
.....

```
at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getSetterCall(SetterStore.java:672)
at android.databinding.tool.Binding.getListenerParameter(Binding.java:164)
at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:200)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:149)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:82)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:85)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
... 90 more
```

Message log says this

```
Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
failure, see logs for details.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
```

from what I read I have made sure of primitive data type conversions in ternary operator. 
I still don't know which model/ binding is causing it.

The code has lot of Spinner,Edittext binding with InverBinding Adaptor and BindingAdaptor. I know without code its hard to point out error. But I have my whole project with data binding. I don't know which one to post. Can u shed some light on how would I know where the compilation is failing ?

Thanks

Comment: The gradle console error ends like this. Plz see updated error message for grade and message logs.

Comment: @xrnd Your first comment should have been included in your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have just found how to get the error details by switching gradle version.
I simply changed grade version from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

This post helped me too [InversDataBinding Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818866/cant-get-android-two-way-data-binding-to-work-intellij-idea)

hope this helps someone.